# How to pass parameter(email ID) to a c# function from Jquery Ajax call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to call a Web Method of service from a Jquery Ajax call.
Method accepts 3 parameter from the front end and search for the record in the DB.

I am not able to concatinate those 3 parameter properly in the Ajax call :

The Web Method is :

```
public bool FindRecord(string Fname, string Lname, string Email) 
{
    string SQL = "SELECT * FROM contactsSource WHERE (first_name ='" + Fname + "') AND (last_name = '" + Lname + "') AND (email_address_work = '" + Email +"')";
    OleDbDataReader reader = DataAccess.GetData(SQL);
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and the Ajax call I am trying is :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnDownload').click(function() {
                var Fname = $('#Fname').val();
                var Lname = $('#Lname').val();
                var email = $('#Email').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{"Fname":"' + Fname + '", "Lname":"' + Lname + '", "Email":' + email + '}',
                    url: "WebService.asmx/FindRecord",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result.d);
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");
                    }
                });
                //$('.secondary').show(500);
            });
        });    

    </script>
```

But I am keep on getting 500 Internal Server error :

```
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: (Email ID that I am passing).","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email parameter should be enclosed in double quotes, otherwise it will not be parsed properly as a JSON string value. The corrected syntax should be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{"Fname":"' + Fname + '", "Lname":"' + Lname + '", "Email":"' + email + '"}',
    url: "WebService.asmx/FindRecord",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.d);
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");
    }
});
```

Comment: Great Observation @Prutswonder, It worked :) thanks a lot, this is my first experience with Jquery and Ajax

Comment: @Vishal Be sure to read the other answers as well, you are doing this the hard way.  Remember, JSON is *Javascript* Object Notation.

Comment: @Chris Definately I'll try the alternate way's aswell, actually its kind of my first assignment on Jquery and Ajax. Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing your `data` object wrong. Do this instead:

```
data: {Fname: Fname, Lname: Lname, Email: Email }
```

Comment: Yes this is also a better and neat way to do it, thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

No need for quotes..

Try:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {Fname: Fname, Lname: Lname, Email: email},
                url: "WebService.asmx/FindRecord",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result.d);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");
                }
            });
```